# Improve query performance of a JOIN and a sub SELECT

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a query that is rather complex, it has multiple inner joins as well as a sub select. It is performing dreadfully:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT
   SUM(weekly_baskets.servings / 2) AS sum_weekly_baskets_servings_2,
   meal_selections.meal_id AS meal_selections_meal_id 
FROM
   "meal_selections" 
INNER JOIN
   "weekly_baskets" "weekly_baskets_meal_selections" 
      ON "weekly_baskets_meal_selections"."id" = "meal_selections"."weekly_basket_id" 
INNER JOIN
   "weekly_baskets" 
      ON "meal_selections"."weekly_basket_id" = "weekly_baskets"."id" 
WHERE
   "weekly_baskets"."menu_id" = 344 
   AND (
      NOT (EXISTS (SELECT
         1 
      FROM
         "cancellations"  
      WHERE
         ("cancellations"."cancellable_id" = "weekly_baskets"."id") 
         AND ("cancellations"."cancellable_type" = 'WeeklyBasket') 
         AND "cancellations"."active" = 't'))
   ) 
GROUP BY
   meal_selections.meal_id
```

Here's the query plan:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=122273.42..122275.79 rows=787 width=8) (actual time=32313.598..32313.602 rows=13 loops=1)
  Group Key: meal_selections.meal_id
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=26501.36..122208.17 rows=43504 width=8) (actual time=97.199..32292.526 rows=48594 loops=1)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=26501.28..119314.73 rows=19567 width=12) (actual time=97.175..20446.310 rows=16067 loops=1)
              ->  Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=26501.19..87846.01 rows=19567 width=8) (actual time=97.146..20274.526 rows=16067 loops=1)
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on weekly_baskets  (cost=26501.11..62382.74 rows=33112 width=8) (actual time=97.049..15395.178 rows=34502 loops=1)
                          Recheck Cond: (menu_id = 344)
                          Heap Blocks: exact=12414
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_weekly_baskets_on_user_id_and_menu_id  (cost=0.00..26499.45 rows=33112 width=0) (actual time=94.135..94.135 rows=34514 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (menu_id = 344)
                    ->  Index Only Scan using uidx_cancellations_for_active on cancellations  (cost=0.08..0.77 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.141..0.141 rows=1 loops=34502)
                          Index Cond: ((cancellable_id = weekly_baskets.id) AND (cancellable_type = 'WeeklyBasket'::text) AND (active = true))
                          Heap Fetches: 12907
              ->  Index Only Scan using weekly_baskets_pkey on weekly_baskets weekly_baskets_meal_selections  (cost=0.09..1.61 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.004..0.010 rows=1 loops=16067)
                    Index Cond: (id = weekly_baskets.id)
                    Heap Fetches: 16595
        ->  Index Only Scan using index_meal_selections_on_weekly_basket_id_and_meal_id on meal_selections  (cost=0.09..0.14 rows=4 width=8) (actual time=0.508..0.737 rows=3 loops=16067)
              Index Cond: (weekly_basket_id = weekly_baskets_meal_selections.id)
              Heap Fetches: 47391
Planning time: 1.568 ms
Execution time: 32313.715 ms
```

Obviously this is very painful. I've hard about potentially using `LATERAL` joins to optimize this query but haven't been able to wrap my head around it.

Comment: When was the last time you vacuum'ed or vacuum-full'ed your tables? There are some slow-ish nested loops, but the big time-takers are index-only scans (on `meal_selections` and `cancellations`), and the index heap fetch on `weekly_baskets`. It's possible that those tables need some attention, or that they're just very large.

Comment: Last vacuum'd about 6 days ago, was a full manual vacuum. Dead row counts are pretty low. You're right, `meal_selections` has ~5m rows, `cancellations` has ~1.1m rows.

Comment: your join "weekly_baskets" "weekly_baskets_meal_selections" doesn't seem to be getting used anywhere. You should remove it. Unless I am misreading your query, which is possible

Comment: You're right @MichaelRobellard -- doesn't improve performance that much but it definitely is unnecessary, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your sub select to a left join and check it for null, that should help.

```
SELECT
   SUM(weekly_baskets.servings / 2) AS sum_weekly_baskets_servings_2,
   meal_selections.meal_id AS meal_selections_meal_id 
FROM
   "meal_selections" 
INNER JOIN
   "weekly_baskets" "weekly_baskets_meal_selections" 
      ON "weekly_baskets_meal_selections"."id" = "meal_selections"."weekly_basket_id" 
INNER JOIN
   "weekly_baskets" 
      ON "meal_selections"."weekly_basket_id" = "weekly_baskets"."id" 
LEFT JOIN "cancellations" on 
         "cancellations"."cancellable_id" = "weekly_baskets"."id"
         AND "cancellations"."cancellable_type" = 'WeeklyBasket' 
         AND "cancellations"."active" = 't'
WHERE
   "weekly_baskets"."menu_id" = 344 
   AND "cancellations"."cancellable_id" is null
GROUP BY
   meal_selections.meal_id
```

Comment: That doesn't speed the query up sadly.

Comment: can you update your question with the explain analyze on this new proposed query. It seems like a good idea (+1) because NOT IN queries are usually a bit slow and by eliminating it, we ought to get a speed up